# Give an example of a linear subspace $L$ of $H=l^2$ such that there exists no $y\in L$ such that $\|x-y\|=$dist($L,x$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that a subspace that is closed and convex must have a unique y in L such that it is true and that if it is closed presumably then you can have many y. So I am looking for an L which is open in $l^2$? I just cant think of an easy one to pick! Is $L={(a_1,a_2,...)|a_i<1 \mbox{ for all }i}$ a good choice? If so can you show me how i can prove the statement? Thanks

Is this a suitable proof?

$$L={(a_1,a_2,...)|a_i=0 \mbox{ for all } i>N} \mbox{ and } x=(1,1/2,1/4,1/8,...)$$
$$\|x-y\|_2=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=(\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n-\frac{1}{2_{n-1}}|^2+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}})^\frac{1}{2}$$
which will always be greater than zero?

Comment: The alternative to "closed" is not "open". In fact, an open linear subspace is necessarily the entire space, hence closed. And per your title, you want a _linear_ subspace. Can you see that for every non-closed linear subspace $L$ of $H$ there are $x$ such that no closest approximation to $x$ in $L$ exists?

Comment: Not closed$\ne$ open.

Comment: Ok so I am looking for a set that is not closed. Is the one that I defined a good choice? I can understand conceptually what I am trying to do, I just have no idea how to prove it rigorously

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Take all finite subsequences of $l^2$ as $L$ and some $x \in l^2$ such that it has infinitely many non-zero coordinates.

Comment: Now $\|x-y\|_2 = (\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|^2+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2(n-1)}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where N is the value for which $a_i=0$ for all $i>N$. How does this relate to the statement i'm trying to prove? or am i barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Recall definition of the norm please.

Comment: $\|x\|=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$

Comment: Am i trying to show that the value of $\|x-y\|$ is not finite?

Comment: No you are trying to show that $\|x-y\| \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh well sorted! haha

Comment: In fact in your first comment you wrote not $\|x-y\|_2$ but $(\|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention I took the vector x to be (1,1/2,1/4,1/8,...) ie. something that has infinitely non zero terms

Comment: Your proof is not good since $\text{dist}(L, x) > 0$.

Comment: What changes should I make?

Comment: Do not fix $N$.

Comment: so if N is not fixed then the value of $\|x-y\|$ can have multiple values? Therefore it is not well defined?

Comment: Just take $L$ as I said.